# Application access violation because windows is not activated

Tags: c++, testing, access-violation

this is just a question for my interest.
Is it possible that my c++ application is crashing and throwing an access violation because windows is not activated?
I tested the program on several systems and everything works fine, but when I test it on a virtual machine where a windows is not activated it crashes and throws this exception.
Could there be any correlation between it?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Most likely it is because of the bug in your code. You should debug your application to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Chances are 99.9999999999% you invoked Undefined behavior in your code

Comment: but why does it only occur when testing on a system which is not activated?

Comment: Maybe there is some other difference between your systems. Instead of guessing, run it under a debugger and figure out where exactly it crashes.

Comment: Maybe you are not checking return codes and handling the error(s).  Without seeing your code (please post a [mcve]) we are left to guess.

Comment: @linkerGuy : Because it's undefined behavior, it's not consistent where it crashes. For all you know, it might work fine on other systems now, only to crash and ruin your weekend on a friday evening. 
If you can figure out where it crashes, provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the crash log, you might get more helpful answers. :)

Comment: ok thank you the only problem for me is that the program crashes at a call of a dll function so it isn't really possible for me to debug it sensible

Answer (score 0):

I see no correlation with Windows not being activated, in this case it should give a comprehensible enough error, but you have two variables here:

- Windows is not activated
- You have a virtual machine

Other than running a debugger like others suggested, I'd troubleshoot the problem running your program on a real machine with a window not activated and in a virtual machine with an activated window.

Chances are that the problem is the virtual machine itself and not window not being activated.